# How to handle an unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hid

I am listing all the USB applications in C# winforms application and trying to use foot pedal to play audio.

I am getting the below error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Destination array is not long enough to copy
>   all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.

```
private void ReadProcess(HidReport report)
{
    byte[] message = report.Data;
    uint _message;
    Array.Reverse(message);
    _message = BitConverter.ToUInt32(message, 0); // exception here!
    ....
```

Comment: Put a big arrow at the statement that throws this exception.  And post the stack trace.

Comment: I have edited the question with specific line throwing error as well as the full code..  Please help.

Comment: The exception message already contains the information you need. The buffer is not big enough to decode a 32-bit unsigned integer from. A 32-bit integer needs 4 bytes, to avoid this problem, check if the buffer (`message`)  is at least 4 bytes in length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `BitConverter.ToUInt32(byte[] value, int startIndex)` throws
>   [ArgumentException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) when startIndex is greater than or equal to the
>   length of value minus 3, and is less than or equal to the length of
>   value minus 1.

The problem is in `report.Data` because it does not meets the requirements to be converted.

You can always wrap your code in [try-catch-finally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and handle the exception but I suggest you to [read more about different type of exceptions and how you should handle them](http://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean just to handle specific exception, just use `try/catch` and explicitely say what type of a exception you want to catch:

```
try
{
   byte[] message = report.Data;
   uint _message;
   Array.Reverse(message);
   _message = BitConverter.ToUInt32(message, 0);
} catch(ArgumentException ex)
{
   // Your logic...
}
```

Since you did not share where exactly the exception occurs I cannot determine what to check, but you should try to validate parameters if possible and either throw your own exception or return specific error.